# ViewPager cluttering fragments on FragmentsPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm implementing a `SherlockFragmentActivity` with a `ViewPager` embedded. The ViewPager appears correctly, however the content inside of it (the fragments itself), are mixed.

> In my situation, I have a view pager with three tabs, I want to load a
>   fragment for each tab. What happens is: the second fragment is loaded
>   in the first tab, and when I click the third tab and go back to the
>   second one, it is showing in there.

Also, when I click the second tab, it loads the fragment of the first tab, and suddenly, loads the content of the second tab, overriding the previous content.

It's loading wrong contents in different tabs.

---

**UPDATE**

While debugging, I've seen that when I open the second tab (added to the `TabsAdapter` as `ContactActivityFragment`), it calls the `onActivityCreated` method and `getView` of the adapter class of `ContactInfoFragment`, which is the first tab, not the second. So the content of the first tab is loaded in the wrong place.

---

Here is my code. Any idea of what might be happening?

**ContactActivity.java**

```
public class ContactActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements     OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
{

public ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager  mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

private TextView mContactNameTextView;
private ImageView mContactIconImageView;

private Context mContext;

private final String FRAGMENT_POSITION = "fragment_position";
private final String CONTACT_ID = "contact_id"; 
private Long mContactId;

private ContactController mContactController;
private Contact mContact;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSherlock.setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

    setContentView(R.layout.contact_activity);

    // retrieve the extra values from the intent
    mContactId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(CONTACT_ID);

    // set the tab host to hold the fragments and the viewpager
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

    // create the bundle to set the values to send to the fragment
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong(CONTACT_ID, mContactId);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragment_contact_title_info)), ContactInfoFragment.class, bundle);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("activity").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragment_contact_title_activity)), ContactActivityFragment.class, bundle);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("stats").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragment_contact_title_stats)), ContactStatsFragment.class, bundle);

    mContext = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();

    // Set the action bar properties
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    // initialize the elements
    mContactNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewContactName);
    mContactIconImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewContactIcon);

    // initialize the contact controller
    mContactController = new ContactController(mContext);

    // initialize the contact object
    mContact = new Contact();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{    
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {        
        // If the user clicks the home icon 
        case android.R.id.home:            
            Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(FRAGMENT_POSITION, "4");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        default:            
            break;  
   }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    mContact = mContactController.getContactById(mContactId);

    // set the action bar title as the contact name. 
    // if the name is null, print the phone number which is set as 
    // the id of the contact in case it's an unmapped contact 
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mContact.getmDisplayName() == null ? mContact.getM_id().toString() : mContact.getmDisplayName());

    // set the contact name.
    // if the name is null, print the phone number which is set as 
    // the id of the contact in case it's an unmapped contact
    mContactNameTextView.setText(mContact.getmDisplayName() == null ? mContact.getM_id().toString() : mContact.getmDisplayName());

    // retrieve the contact image based on the URI
    Bitmap contactIconBitmap = mContactController.getContactPicture(mContactId);
    mContactIconImageView.setImageBitmap(contactIconBitmap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // do nothing, since the menu items must be added on specific fragments
    return true;
}

/**
 * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
 * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
 * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
 * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
 * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
 * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
 * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
 * tab changes.
 */
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener 
{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo 
    {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) 
        {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory 
    {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) 
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) 
        {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) 
    {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) 
    {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
    {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
    {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) 
    {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
    {
    }   
}   
}
```

**ContactInfoFragment.java**

```
public class ContactInfoFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
private Activity mActivity;
private Menu mOptionsMenu;
private ListView mListView;

private final String CONTACT_ID = "contact_id"; 
private Long mContactId;
private List<Contact> mContactsData = new ArrayList<Contact>();
private List<PhoneNumber> mPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
private final String[] mListHeaders = { "Phone Numbers" };

private ContactController mContactController;
private PhoneNumberController mPhoneNumberController;
private Contact mContact;
private PhoneNumber mPhoneNumber;
private SeparatedListAdapter mSeparatedListAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState = getArguments();

    // set the contact id
    mContactId = savedInstanceState.getLong(CONTACT_ID);

    // initialize controllers
    mContactController = new ContactController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mPhoneNumberController = new PhoneNumberController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("class_name", "ContactInfoFragment");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // inflate the layout 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_info_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mContact = mContactController.getContactById(mContactId);
    mPhoneNumbers = mPhoneNumberController.getPhoneNumbersByContact(mContact);

    mListView = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    ContentAdapter mAdapter = new ContentAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.id.list, mPhoneNumbers);

    // add the items for the adapter
    for (PhoneNumber phoneNumber : mPhoneNumbers)
    {
        mAdapter.add(phoneNumber);
    } 

    mSeparatedListAdapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(mActivity.getApplicationContext());

    // Add Sections
    mSeparatedListAdapter.addSection("Phone Numbers", mAdapter);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mSeparatedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(mSeparatedListAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) 
        {
            // if the user clicks a number, it will open the dialer to call the number
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+view.getTag(R.string.phone_number_action_call).toString()));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater)
{
    mOptionsMenu = menu;

    menu.add("People")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Share")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
}

private void changeOptionsMenu(int position)
{
    mOptionsMenu.clear();

    if(position == 0)
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
    else if(position == 1)
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Days")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_days)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
    else
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
}

public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneNumber>
{
    Context mContext;
    List<PhoneNumber> mPhoneNumbersList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        this.mPhoneNumbersList = phoneNumbers;
        mInflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    // An alternative for the ArrayAdapter.addAll() method, since the native 
    // is not supported by API level lesser then 11.
    public void addAll(ArrayList<PhoneNumber> list)
    {
        for(PhoneNumber phoneNumber : list)
        {
            this.add(phoneNumber);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null)
        {
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_info_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.phoneNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewContactNumber);
            holder.phoneNumberType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumberType);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        // TODO: make a join to get the contact and phone number instead of calling method by method
        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = mPhoneNumbersList.get(position);

        if(phoneNumber != null)
        {
            holder.phoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber.getmPhoneNumberValue());
            holder.phoneNumberType.setText(CallUtils.getPhoneNumberType(phoneNumber.getmPhoneNumberType()));
            row.setTag(R.string.phone_number_action_call, phoneNumber.getmPhoneNumberValue());
        }

        return row;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    TextView phoneNumber;
    TextView phoneNumberType;
}
}
```

**ContactActivityFragment.java**

```
public class ContactActivityFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
private Activity mActivity;
private Menu mOptionsMenu;
private ListView mListView;

private final String CONTACT_ID = "contact_id"; 
private Long mContactId;
private List<Contact> mContactsData = new ArrayList<Contact>();
private List<Call> mCallsList = new ArrayList<Call>();
private final String[] mListHeaders = { "Calls" };

private Call mCall;
private Contact mContact;
private PhoneNumber mPhoneNumber;
private CallController mCallController;
private ContactController mContactController;
private PhoneNumberController mPhoneNumberController;
private SeparatedListAdapter mSeparatedListAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState = getArguments();

    // set the contact id
    mContactId = savedInstanceState.getLong(CONTACT_ID);

    // initialize controllers
    mCallController = new CallController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mContactController = new ContactController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mPhoneNumberController = new PhoneNumberController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // initialize models
    mCall = new Call();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("class_name", "ContactInfoFragment");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // inflate the layout 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_info_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mCallsList = mCallController.getCallsByContact(mContactId);

    mContact = mContactController.getContactById(mContactId);

    mListView = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    ContentAdapter mAdapter = new ContentAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.id.list, mCallsList);

    // add the items for the adapter
    for (Call callList : mCallsList)
    {
        mAdapter.add(callList);
    } 

    mSeparatedListAdapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(mActivity.getApplicationContext());

    // Add Sections
    mSeparatedListAdapter.addSection("Phone Numbers", mAdapter);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mSeparatedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(mSeparatedListAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater)
{
    mOptionsMenu = menu;

    menu.add("People")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Share")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
}

private void changeOptionsMenu(int position)
{
    mOptionsMenu.clear();

    if(position == 0)
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
    else if(position == 1)
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Days")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_days)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
    else
    {
        mOptionsMenu.add("People")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        mOptionsMenu.add("Share")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
}

public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Call>
{
    Context mContext;
    List<Call> mCallsList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Call> calls) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        this.mCallsList = calls;
        mInflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    // An alternative for the ArrayAdapter.addAll() method, since the native 
    // is not supported by API level lesser then 11.
    public void addAll(ArrayList<Call> callsList)
    {
        for(Call call : callsList)
        {
            this.add(call);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null)
        {
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_info_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.phoneNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewContactNumber);
            holder.phoneNumberType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumberType);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        // TODO: make a join to get the contact and phone number instead of calling method by method
        Call call = mCallsList.get(position);

        if(call != null)
        {
            holder.phoneNumber.setText(call.getCallDuration().toString());
            holder.phoneNumberType.setText(call.getCallDate());
        }

        return row;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    TextView phoneNumber;
    TextView phoneNumberType;
} 
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. For me the number of fragments is set dynamically.